# Best way to check if Nautilus File Manager is running?

Tags: gnome, desktop, nautilus, icons

I've been working hours on this problem. When nautilus file manager is NOT running nautilus is running because it controls icons on the desktop.

```bash
$ ps -aux | grep nautilus | grep -v grep
rick      5613  0.2  1.7 2355392 140012 pts/19 Sl+  19:04   0:08 nautilus
```

So use this command without nautilus file manager open and you see:

```bash
$ ps -L -p 5613 -o pid,nice,lwp,comm
  PID  NI   LWP COMMAND
 5613   0  5613 nautilus
 5613   0  5614 gmain
 5613   0  5615 gdbus
 5613   0  5617 dconf worker
```

Now open up nautilus file manager and redo `ps` command:

```bash
$ nautilus

$ ps -L -p 5613 -o pid,nice,lwp,comm
  PID  NI   LWP COMMAND
 5613   0  5613 nautilus
 5613   0  5614 gmain
 5613   0  5615 gdbus
 5613   0  5617 dconf worker
 5613   0  4788 pool
```

Close the nautilus files window and rerun the command (after waiting a second or two) and the pool disappears.

Is this the correct way of seeing if nautilus file manager is running?

I've incorporated above technique into an answer in **Ask Ubuntu** I'd like to improve if possible:

- [How can I automatically relaunch nautilus if I quit the program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180043/how-can-i-automatically-relaunch-nautilus-if-i-quit-the-program/1180596#1180596)

Comment: +1 for looking into and explaining the details of this problem :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to check whether there are any Nautilus windows open is to check for them on the session D-Bus:

```
gdbus introspect --session --dest org.gnome.Nautilus \
      --object-path /org/gnome/Nautilus --recurse | awk '/^ *node /{print $2}'
```

This will show window entries under `/org/gnome/Nautilus/window` if there are any open windows; so

```
gdbus introspect --session --dest org.gnome.Nautilus \
      --object-path /org/gnome/Nautilus --recurse |
grep -q '^ *node /org/gnome/Nautilus/window/'
```

will succeed if there are any open windows, fail otherwise.

Comment: With desktop icons and no browser I get `.../window/1` with file browser that plus `.../window/9`. On fresh reboot no file browser still `.../window/1` with files open get that plus `.../window/3`. Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS - `GNOME nautilus 3.14.3` **Note:** Files does autostart on login and I have to close it for testing.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, so the desktop counts as a window too (at least in some setups). Let’s see if I can find something better...

Comment: Better would be best but I did get it working appending `grep -v '/window/1` my only concern is there might be more than one gnome app that uses a window which would give a false positive that file browser is running.